# Woocommerce remove order item meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin that adds custom meta to Woocommerce Order Items.

In certain circumstances I'd like to be able to remove them (or rename them).

Along with `wc_add_order_item_meta()` and `wc_update_order_item_meta()`, though, I wasn't able to find a function to delete them.

I guess I could use update with a `null` value, but I'm not sure if that is functionally equivalent to it.

Answer (score 5):

```
wc_delete_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key );
```

or even this

```
delete_post_meta( $order_item_id, 'your_meta_key');
```